# ElasticSearch API under Data Tables fnServerData

Tags: elasticsearch, datatable, datatables

I want to fill the datatable data from elasticsearch js api. For that I have a code like this.

```
        var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
            columns: [
                { title: "Title" }
            ],
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bServerSide': true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bSort": false,
            "asStripeClasses": [],
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                aoData.push(
                    {"name":"search", "value": $('#title_search').val()},
                );
            },
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                var searchval,sortval,sortorder;
                aoData.map(function(i) {
                    var search = i.name;
                    if(search =='search') {
                        searchval = i.value;
                    }

                });
                /*Query ElasticSearch */
                client.search({
                        index: indexname,
                        type: indextype,
                        from: 0,
                        size: 10,
                        body: {
                            query: {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": searchval + '*',
                                    "fields": ["title", "number"]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, function (error, response) {
                        fnCallback(response);
                    });

            }

        });
```

I am able to fetch the results from the above call. But, when I try to search in the Data Table, the results are appending for every letter searching.

```
function search(e) {
      otTable.fnDraw();
 }
```

For Example, I try to search for `London`. When I type L it is appending all results starting with letter L, and when I type O then it is again appending all results starting with `Lo`.

I am getting the correct response from ES, I think there is a problem at Data Tables end while appending the data.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I'd check what you're sending back to AWS as it looks as though for LONDON, for instance, you send an array with "L" and then "O"... alternatively, if you just send one request for each letter (so one request for "L", then another for "O") then you might need to empty the table before drawing it again...

Comment: @annoyingmouse Thought of same.  I tried to clear the table data before calling the callback with `oTable.fnClearTable();`. But, it didn't help.

Comment: can you try adding otTable= $('#myTable').dataTable(); in search function before draw?

Comment: @Devika, but are you sending an array of characters of a string with both...? Perhaps a simple JSFiddle might help... though perhaps not in light of needing to interact with AWS - I'd suggest having a look at the Network tab - and what version of DataTables are you using?

Comment: @annoyingmouse Data Table version 1.9.1

Comment: @shubham Thanks for the help. I tried to recreate the datatable object in search function, it didn't work.